# How could I insert a \section tag inside a \multicolumn tag?

Tags: tables, sectioning, multicolumn, xtab

is it possible to define a `\section` inside a `\multicolumn` in a `xtab` table?. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{TestSectionA}

\begin{xtabular}{|lp{\textwidth}|}
  \hline
  & bla bla 1\\
  \hline
  & \section{TestSectionB}  \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\section{TestSectionC}}  \\
  \hline
  & bla bla 2\\
  \hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX stops when detects this tag: `\section{TestSectionC}`. How could I workaround it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you want to have section breaks inside an `xtabular`. Can you explain better the context? There are probably different ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's very bad form to put section commands in a table, it implies the logical structure of the document is messed up somehow.

But if you must, they need to be in *vertical* mode so `p` not `c` entry.

```
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\section{TestSectionC}}  \\
```

works, note you need something like

```
\begin{xtabular}{|lp{.7\textwidth}|}
```

as if you make the second column textwidth wide there is no room for the first column.